# How do I see the tags created by me?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I just created a tag and found only the following stats:

> [image: stats]

How do I find the tags created by me, at a later point in time?

I have created few tags before, how do I know when a tag created by me is burned, or merged with something else..?

Is there anything in the system currently which indicates that a tag is created by me?

Or in other words, how do I know my progress towards the [Taxonomist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) badge? Do I have to remember tags created by me..?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10888/how-does-one-find-which-tags-they-created

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use data.SE - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/87763/how-close-are-you-to-a-taxonomist-badge

[Or a general search result](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=taxonomist)

But [I like what Jeff says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress/34440#34440) —

> Some of the badges are supposed to be surprises, not World of Warcraft
> style level grinds based on numbers.
>
> I worry that if we provide too many metrics:
>
> - it becomes noise, like a bunch of inscrutable F-16 cockpit gauges -- how are all these numbers *useful* except for these specific badges?
> - the badge becomes the explicit goal instead of the desired behavior
> - the badges are no longer a pleasant surprise and reward but an expected "level up"